# Is there a const for the default value of the Date variable type, a la vbNullString for the string type?

Tags: variables, date, excel, default-value, vba

I have a column of dates. These will be incorporated into objects, one per row, along with other data in the row.

However, some of the cells in the date column are empty. As I test I create a date variable and set its value as the value of an empty cell. I msgbox'd the new value of the date and found it was "12:00 AM". Is there a constant built into VBA to represent this value, so I can do tests similar to:

```
If myDate = vbNullDate Then
```

Comment: In this case the constant is merely zero.

Comment: Thanks andy, didn't realise it was that simple

Comment: You should note that Excel/VBA is different from other programs in that it doesn't actually have a `DateTime` data type. Instead it uses a `double` data type to store dates/times and formats them on the screen to look like dates.

Answer (score 8):

I run into this problem from time to time. I usually do the below:

```
dim d as date
if d = cdate(0) then msgbox "Default value"
```

Answer (score 4):

The default value for a local Date variable seems to be:

`Saturday, December 30, 1899 12:00:00 AM`

based on this procedure:

```
Sub testdate()

Dim d As Date

Debug.Print Format$(d, "Long Date") & " " & Format$(d, "Long Time")

End Sub
```

To check the default value for any variable type, simply declare a variable of that type, then print it's value.

```
Sub testint()

Dim d As Integer

Debug.Print d

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As andy holaday said in the comment below the question, the default value of a date is simply 0. Silly me :/